# Is there a trick how to draw such a graph?

Tags: analysis, graphing-functions, submanifold

I'm considering the following set $$M=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2: y(y^2-x)=0\}$$ And I want to show that this is not a submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^2$. So it is clear that the critical point is $(0,0)$ but I thought that maybye there is a simple trick how to draw such a graph $$y(y^2-x)=0$$
Therefore I wanted to ask you if there is something like a general or very useful trick so that I can think really geometrically about such an equation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133821/discussion-on-question-by-aprozz-is-there-a-trick-how-to-draw-such-a-graph).

Comment: Probably of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125595/geometric-intuition-of-the-tangent-cone